# Casting one object to another type

Tags: c#, user-controls, casting, as-operator

I have one class named A and one class B

```
public class A : UserControl { }

public class B : UserControl { }
```

Now i have one assembly whose class's function accepts objects of class A. This assembly is not created by me so i don't have any control. Basically it is 3rd party assembly.

But i want to supply my objects of class B since it is bit customized. Rest assured it contains all properties of class A. How can i typecast my object of class B to type A so that i can integrate 3rd party assembly in my project as well as customize the look and feel according to my needs?

If i so something like `(A)objB` it is not allowed. Then i tried this:

```
UserControl control = objB as UserControl;

A objA = control as A;
```

But problem in this case is objA is null.

To avoid confusion: class A and assembly is provided by 3rd party.

Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Given your hierarchy, you will have to write a conversion operator. There is no built-in way to do this in general (think `Dog : Animal` and `Cat : Animal`):

```
public static explicit operator A(B b) {
    // code to populate a new instance of A from b
}
```

You could also use a generic reflection framework and do something like

```
public static void PropertyCopyTo<TSource, TDesination>(
    this TSource source,
    TDestination destination
) {
    // details elided
}
```

so then you could say

```
// b is B
// a is A
b.PropertyCopyTo<A>(a);
```

which would copy all the common properties between `b` to `a`.

Comment: You're not casting, you're converting.

Comment: @Nicolas Repiquet: "A cast-expression of the form `(T)E`, where `T` is a type and `E` is a unary-expression, performs an explicit conversion (§6.2) of the value of `E` to type `T`." Additionally, from the grammar, "`cast-expression: (type) unary-expression`" so that by defining an explicit conversion operator I enable the expression `(A)b` to be accepted by the compiler as a cast expression casting `b` to an instance of `A`.

Comment: @Rune FS: See reply there. You are taking too narrow of a definition of the word "cast."

Answer (score 2):

For `B` to be castable to a `A`, `B` must *inherits* `A`. Even if `B` contains all properties of `A`, it's still not a `A`.

Comment: Wrong; he could write a custom conversion operator.

Comment: ... A conversion operator is nothing more than creating a new A instance with a B as parameter. B is still not a A. Learn your basics please.

Comment: @Nicolas Repiquet: Humility, you needs it. I refer you to http://bit.ly/Vr5R1 where explicit conversions are clearly described as casts. I further refer you to the C# specification: "A cast-expression is used to explicitly convert an expression to a given type. `cast-expression: (type) unary-expression` A cast-expression of the form `(T)E`, where `T` is a type and `E` is a unary-expression, performs an explicit conversion (§6.2) of the value of `E` to type `T`." By defining an explicit conversion operator, we permit `B` to be cast to `A` thus negating your statement that `B` must inherit `A`.

Comment: @Nicolas Repiquet : Yes you are right it is still not A but it can fit nicely with my needs. I can create an instance of A and with conversion operator populate A with properties of B and pass that A to 3rd party assembly. I think it should solve my problem. Somebody downvoted. But i will upvote you since your suggestion is not wrong.

Comment: @Jason: we are not talking about immutable value types here, where creating a new value with another _could_ be viewed as casting. Your conversion operator create a new instance of `A` with a `B` as parameter. Changes made on the `A` instance will not be reflected on `B`. It's not casting.

Comment: @Jason eventhough the term is cast-expression. It's simply a method returning an object of the needed type it's not an upcast as OP needs. After all he's talking about properties aka method calls, so simply returning an object that upon creation _might_ return the same values does not make it possible for him to _us_ objects of type B as objects of type A. Which is what he asks for

Comment: @Nicolas Repiquet, @Rune FS: "In the C family of languages, the word "cast" typically refers to an explicit type conversion (as opposed to an implicit conversion), regardless of whether this is a re-interpretaion of a bit-pattern or a real conversion." From: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Type_conversion

Comment: @Jason but as state above by both me and Nicolas in different manners calling a method on the result of the conversion operator will not have the same effect as if it had been an actual cast. In this case a conversion did solve the problem but that doesn't change that your answer might have yield an undesirable result when a virtual method is called on the result of the "cast" and that's complete independent of how people choose to view a specific term

Comment: @Rune FS: You put more restrictive conditions on the use of the word "cast," not the OP, and not me. It is better to answer the question that is asked; if it doesn't suffice for the OP's purposes he can refine the question. And you can't say "an actual cast", as I've already exhibited a conversion is a cast.

Comment: @Jason as stated repeatedly OP is taking about method calls on the object. for your answer to correctly answer the question as stated (as opposed to the actual situation) the question would need refinement not the other way around

Comment: @Rune FS: Repeatedly? Method calls on the object? Are we reading the same question?

Comment: @Jason properties are nothing but syntactic sugar for methods set_xx and get_xx

Answer (score 1):

you may use an Adapter pattern

[See Here](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/rmcochran/csharp_wrapper402122006091959AM/csharp_wrapper4.aspx)

Comment: What's with all the -1's on every answer (directed at whoever did that). Using a wrapper (adapter pattern) is a perfectly cromulent solution to this problem.

Comment: @Fredrick Pennachi: There is some serious angst going on in here; I don't understand what is wrong with my answer to garner two downvotes?

Comment: @Fredrick Pennachi ,@ Jason : i also don't understand  i seems somebuddy is really frustated out here :)

Answer (score 0):

If B cannot be cast to A (as in `B is A`)
it is not possible to achieve what you are trying to do without inheriting from A. Unfortunately C# doesn't support [duck typing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Duck_Typing) unlike many dynamic languages (i.e. Ruby).

Answer (score -1):

You can inherit from class A:

```
public class B : A {
}
```

And if you need to overrride some methods/properties just set them to `virtual` in class A.

Answer (score -1):

I think you actually cannot do it.

Why not adding your properties to a partial class A?